# Showing hemisphere is orientated

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis

I've got one thing left proofing for that one task:

The orientability of a hemisphere with the parameterization $$\psi(\varphi, \theta) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta)\\ \cos(\theta)\end{array}\right), \quad \varphi \in[0,2\,\pi] \quad \theta\in[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$$

Now, as usual with the unit Normal Vector given by: $$N = \dfrac{\partial_\varphi\psi \times\partial_\theta\psi}{\vert \partial_\varphi\psi \times\partial_\theta\psi \vert} = N = \left(\begin{array}{c}-\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ -\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right)
$$
However I don't really can incorporate this in the definition of orientated surfaces one gave us:

A surface is oriented if for each parametrisation $\psi(u,v)$ $$ \pm N\circ\psi = \dfrac{\partial_u\psi \times\partial_v\psi}{\vert \partial_v\psi \times\partial_v\psi \vert}$$

Does this imply I just have to show $$N = \dfrac{\partial_\theta\psi \times\partial_\varphi\psi}{\vert \partial_\theta\psi \times\partial_\varphi\psi \vert} = N = \left(\begin{array}{c}\cos(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta) \\ \cos(\theta)\end{array}\right) \quad ?$$

I just can't imagine how to cover all parameterizations

Comment: Usual surfaces have two sides - inside and outside. If you orient the surface such that outside is positive then the normal vector should be pointing outward and vice versa.

Comment: A question should tell you how the surface is oriented. Worst case if it does not, we consider outward normal vector.

Comment: For this specific problem, if you are considering outward normal vector you should use $\partial_\theta\psi \times\partial_\varphi\psi$. Simply look at it this way - for _given_ hemisphere with $z \geq 0$, outward normal vector to the spherical surface will generally point in the positive z-direction. So choose one which has $\hat k$ component as $\cos\theta$ instead of one which has $-\cos\theta$.

Comment: @Leon Your definition of oriented doesn't make sense; it seems to just be a definition of the coordinate form of the unit normal vector (up to sign). You might want to review how orientations and orientability are defined.

Comment: Intuitively it's totally clear the upper semi-sphere is orientated? But I'm asking you- how do I show by definition the surface is an orientated one, in other words, the unit -normal vector is not jumping? I barely can find any formal definitions here. I believe remembering a surface is orientable if N is a differentiable vector-field. Or just continuous? Does this count?

Comment: Just saw this comment. By definition, if we can choose a unit normal field that is normal to every point on the surface, the surface is orientable. The other definition that I have seen is that if we can choose a consistent direction for all loops on the surface, then it is orientable.